# OpenMP nested loop skips some of the combinations

Tags: c, openmp

I am creating a string matching parallel program with the use of OpenMP. 
Here's the code to match a two-character string.

```
void compare2(char *str) //str = 2 character string pass from main(). (for e.g. "aa")
{
    char str1[2];
    int flag = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(alphabet); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<strlen(alphabet); j++)
        {
            if(flag)
            {
                continue;
            }
            str1[0] = alphabet[i];
            str1[1] = alphabet[j];
            str1[2] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", str1);

            if(strcmp(str1, str) == 0)
            {
                printf("Match found %d!\n", omp_get_thread_num());
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have observed that some of the combinations like "aa", "bc", etc. are frequently "skipped".
Also, I don't face this problem when I specify the number of threads as `num_threads(1)`. The problem occurs when the `num_threads() > 1`. 
 Note - The flag variable has been added to skip the output once the match is found.

Comment: You are declaring local array `str1` with capacity for two characters, but you are trying to use three.  Trying to write to `str1[2]` produces undefined behavior.

Comment: not doing the `str1[2] = '\0'` produces garbage value in the output.

Comment: And that's the only solution you can think of for the length problem?

Comment: Okay won't lie, but why is this behavior happening?
I declared a char[2] and am assigning two values at 0th and 1st index. The compiler should add a null terminator by default. Why is it producing garbage value?

Comment: Note: a quick search refreshed my memory about the array declaration.

Comment: You are also sharing flag and assuming that its value will be immediately visible to other threads when stored. The OpenMP memory model makes no such promise. You therefore need OpenMP flush statements to ensure that teh shared variable is visible appropriately. https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu96.html (Your code will likely work on X86 with strong emory ordering guarantees but could fail on other architectures with more relaxed memory models).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `str1` not being long enough for your purpose, you have the additional major issue of data races involving that variable.  It will be shared by the threads executing your parallel section, which will result in them stomping all over each other's data, or worse.  It is not particularly surprising that this manifests as some combinations tending to be skipped.

But this should be pretty easy to solve.  Best practice for variable declarations is to place them in the narrowest scope that permits them to serve their purpose.  You use that array only inside the innermost loop of your loop nest, and you do not rely on it to keep its value across iterations, so you should declare it inside that loop.  Doing so will have the additional effect of preventing the problematic sharing, so that's an all-around win.  Something along these lines:

```
void compare2(char *str) //str = 2 character string pass from main(). (for e.g. "aa")
{
    int flag = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(alphabet); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(alphabet) && flag == 0; j++) {
            if(flag) {
                continue;
            }

            char str1[3] = { alphabet[i], alphabet[j] };

            printf("%s\n", str1);

            if (strcmp(str1, str) == 0) {
                printf("Match found %d!\n", omp_get_thread_num());
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```